# Getting CONSCRYPT in Android using ExoPlayer

Tags: android, exoplayer

I am making a simple video streaming app using CDN with ExoPlayer. Everything was working just fine a few days ago. But all of sudden I started getting below error.

I believe it is something relating to HTTPS but not sure. I am seeing such an error the first time in my life. :S

I found on [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-ssl#java) but I don't understand how to use it to connect with my URL.

## URL

```
String STREAMING_URL = "https://live.xyz.com/sdfgyu456fgr8345dfgdgdgjttyfgndr.sdp/index.m3u8";
        Uri mp4VideoUri = Uri.parse(STREAMING_URL);
```

## Error

```
E/CONSCRYPT: ------------------Untrusted chain: ----------------------
    == Chain0 == 
     Version:   3
E/CONSCRYPT:  AuthorityKeyIdentifier:   5345...
              SubjectKeyIdentifier:   45343...
E/CONSCRYPT:  Serial Number:   56786...
E/CONSCRYPT:  SubjectDN:   CN=*.xyzcdn.com
E/CONSCRYPT:  IssuerDN:   CN= Bla bla .. 
E/CONSCRYPT:  Get not before:   Time stamp here ..
E/CONSCRYPT:  Get not after:   Time stamp here ..
E/CONSCRYPT:  Sig ALG name:   SHA256withRSA
E/CONSCRYPT:  Signature:   -5446446545664asdfsjsad4sad57 ........
E/CONSCRYPT:  Public key: 0000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the SSL configuration. Resolved after fix SSL configuration.

Comment: How did you fix SSL Cinfiguration??? i am having the same issue?